Mt. Gox Exchange currency list
I am studying crypto-assets and wanted to know if there is a list of fiat currencies that could be exchanged for Bitcoin before its bankruptcy. Does anyone have any sources on this topic?
Thank you in advance!

You can check the copies of old mtgox.com web pages in the internet archive (wayback machine).
For example, https://web.archive.org/web/20121112054338/https://support.mtgox.com/entries/20490576-withdrawals-and-deposits lists

USD, EUR, CAD, CHF, AUD, HKD, YEN, MYR, NZD, SAR, SEK, and THB

However, I think you might need to search a wider set of archived pages from the same date.
